# create file in directory without x permission set on directory : How?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, filesystems

From this page, http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/aunix1/filepermissions.htm, I understand that I need the +w bit set in a directory to create a new file and +x bit to cd into it/access its inode. So far, so good. But, I can't use vi/cat/nano/echo etc to do stuff like:

```
echo hello > dir/file
```

because I can't access inode of dir. My question is, how do I create/delete/rename a new file in dir  if I can't access its inode ? Can I edit the directory structure using

```
vi dir
```

and create/edit/rename a new file? Is there a tutorial to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have `+x` even if you have `+w`, you can not create new entries in the directory, neither files nor directories.

Comment: If you don't have +x, to my knowledge, you can't even cd to that directory? And if you can't even cd to that directory, it then implies you can't do any action into the directory? Why not chmod the directory and add +x on it?

Comment: I wanted to understand the point of +w used alone on directories. So, even to create a new file, I need +x ?

Answer (score 5):

The `x` permission on directories is a "lookup" permission. It is needed to get hold of dentry in the directory by name.

Since each and every filesystem operation starts with a lookup on the target path, you have absolutely no access to content of a directory where you don't have `x` permission. There is thus no point in having `w` without `x`, because creating dentries in the directory requires lookup permission there.

The fact that you can't `cd` is kind of side-effect, because it looks up `.` inside the directory, not just the directory itself (you still can `stat` the directory).